# (Async. Socket in C#) I do NOT receive the message every time..

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, client-server

I have the following client/ server code in C#, I tested on two computers, they can connect successfully and does not have any problem with the connection

**The Problem:** when I try sending messages between them, sometimes the message will not be received on the destination computer until them destination send back a message.

Any help is appropriated..

**Server:::**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    private int size = 1024;
    private Socket server;
    private Socket client ;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        stopListining.Enabled = false;
        server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
        SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);            
    }
    private void startListining_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 20916);
        server.Bind(iep);
        server.Listen(5);
        server.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptConn), server);

        startListining.Enabled = false;
        stopListining.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void stopListining_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        client.Close();
        stopListining.Enabled = false;
        startListining.Enabled = true;
    }
    void AcceptConn(IAsyncResult iar)
    {
        Socket server = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;
        client = server.EndAccept(iar);

        conStatuss("Connected to: " + client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

        string stringData = "Server:: Welcome to my server";
        byte[] message1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringData);
        client.BeginSend(message1, 0, message1.Length, SocketFlags.None,
                    new AsyncCallback(SendData), client);
    }
    void SendData(IAsyncResult iar)
    {
        Socket client = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;
        int sent = client.EndSend(iar);
        client.BeginReceive(data, 0, size, SocketFlags.None,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveData), client);
    }
    void ReceiveData(IAsyncResult iar)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket client = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;
            int recv = client.EndReceive(iar);
            if (recv == 0)
            {
                client.Close();
                conStatuss("Waiting for client...");
                server.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptConn), server);
                return;
            }
            string receivedData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
            addResult(receivedData+"\"R("+DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt")+")\"");

            //to send back received text
             /*
              byte[] message2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(receivedData);
            client.BeginSend(message2, 0, message2.Length, SocketFlags.None,
                        new AsyncCallback(SendData), client);
              */ 

        }
        catch (Exception eee)
        {
            conStatuss(eee.ToString());
        }
    }

    delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
    private void conStatuss(string text)
    {
        // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
        // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
        // If these threads are different, it returns true.
        if (this.statetxt.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(conStatuss);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
            this.statetxt.Text = text;
        }
    }

    public delegate void AddListBoxItem(string message);
    public void addResult(string message)
    {
        //TODO: find out whats going on here
        if (resultss.InvokeRequired)
        {
            //TODO: Which works better?
            //AddListBoxItem albi = AddString;
            //listBox.Invoke( albi, message );
            resultss.Invoke(new AddListBoxItem(addResult), message);
        }
        else
            this.resultss.Items.Add(message);
    }

    private void sendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (messageTXT.Text.Trim().ToString().Length == 0)
        {
            conStatuss("Write something to send!");
            return;
        }


        /*
       byte[] byData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(messageTXT.Text);
       client.Send(byData);
       resultss.Items.Add("Server:: "+messageTXT.Text);

         */

        string stringData = "Server:: " + messageTXT.Text+"\"S("+DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt")+")\"";
        addResult(stringData);
        byte[] message1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringData);
        client.BeginSend(message1, 0, message1.Length, SocketFlags.None,
                    new AsyncCallback(SendData), client);
        messageTXT.Clear();
    }
}
```

**Client:::**

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private TextBox newText;
    private TextBox conStatus;
    private ListBox results;
    private Socket client;
    private byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    private int size = 1024;

    public Form1()

    {
        InitializeComponent();
}
void ButtonConnectOnClick(object obj, EventArgs ea)
    {
        conStatus.Text = "Connecting...";
        Socket newsock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                              SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.10.4"), 20916);
        newsock.BeginConnect(iep, new AsyncCallback(Connected), newsock);
    }

    void ButtonSendOnClick(object obj, EventArgs ea)
    {
        if (newText.Text.Trim().ToString().Length == 0)
        {
            conStatuss("Write something to send!");
            return;
        }
        byte[] message = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Client:: " + newText.Text + "\"S(" + DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt") + ")\"");
        addResult("Client:: " + newText.Text + "\"S(" + DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt") + ")\"");
        //client.Send(message);

        client.BeginSend(message, 0, message.Length, SocketFlags.None,
                     new AsyncCallback(SendData), client);
        newText.Clear();
    }

    void ButtonDisconOnClick(object obj, EventArgs ea)
    {
        client.Close();
        conStatus.Text = "Disconnected";
    }

    void Connected(IAsyncResult iar)
    {
        client = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;

        try
        {
            client.EndConnect(iar);
            conStatuss("Connected to: " + client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
            client.BeginReceive(data, 0, size, SocketFlags.None,
                          new AsyncCallback(ReceiveData), client);
        }
        catch (SocketException)
        {
            conStatuss("Error connecting");
        }

    }

    void ReceiveData(IAsyncResult iar)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket remote = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;
            int recv = remote.EndReceive(iar);
            string stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
            addResult(stringData + "\"R(" + DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt") + ")\"");

            /*
            //to send back received text
            byte[] message2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringData);
            client.BeginSend(message2, 0, message2.Length, SocketFlags.None,
                        new AsyncCallback(SendData), client);
             */ 

        }
        catch (Exception eee)
        {
            conStatuss(eee.ToString());
        }

    }

    void SendData(IAsyncResult iar)
    {
        Socket remote = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;
        int sent = remote.EndSend(iar);
        remote.BeginReceive(data, 0, size, SocketFlags.None,
                      new AsyncCallback(ReceiveData), remote);
    }


    delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
    private void conStatuss(string text)
    {
        // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
        // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
        // If these threads are different, it returns true.
        if (this.conStatus.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(conStatuss);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
            this.conStatus.Text = text;
        }
    }

    public delegate void AddListBoxItem(string message);
    public void addResult(string message)
    {
        //TODO: find out whats going on here
        if (results.InvokeRequired)
        {
            //TODO: Which works better?
            //AddListBoxItem albi = AddString;
            //listBox.Invoke( albi, message );
            results.Invoke(new AddListBoxItem(addResult), message);
        }
        else
            this.results.Items.Add(message);
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Is there some reason why are you not using TcpListener and TcpClient?

Comment: I am almost now in socket programming in C#, I used to do it on VB6, it was very simple and easy to use.. 
so, would you please tell me, which one is better?? and what are the differences??

Comment: There is no difference one is just easer to use. Most likely the AsyncCallback for listening on the socket is not executed at the time when you send the message. Try using async and await for they tend to be better for debugging.